# Can not establish 2 DB relationships between 2 tables

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have an October cms 3.x app.
I have 2 models (tables) `Product` and `Category`. I need to establish 2 relationships between them. A `Product` should have 1 `Category` assigned to it. and a `Category` additionally should be able to be assigned 3 different `Product` as a `showcase product`.

1. A `Product` can have a single Category. The `Product` model has `public $belongsTo = [ 'category' => Category::class ];` while the `Category` has `public $hasMany = [ 'products' => Product::class ];`. And in the `Product` field.yml file

```
category:
    label: Category
    type: relation
    span: auto
```

This relationship works.

2. I need to make it so for a `Category` I could assign specific products as a showcase products (used to display in the category page). And this is the problematic part. If i add

```
showcases:
    label: Showcase product
    type: relation
    span: auto
```

to the category field.yml and in the `Category` model I set

```
public $hasMany = [
        'products' => Product::class,
        'showcases' => Product::class
    ];
```

what ends up happening is it displays products that have this specific category selected. And if I edit it, it just changed the product category rather than saving this as a showcase product (new column).

I also tried

```
public $hasMany = [
        'products' => Product::class,
        'showcases' => [
            Product::class,
            'table' => 'category_showcase_products',
            'key' => 'category_id',
            'otherKey' => 'product_id'
        ],
    ];
```

by creating a `category_showcase_products` table that has just 2 columns `category_id` and `product_id`. Still same behavior.

So what should be happening is:

1. A `Product` can have a single category
2. A `Category` can additionally assign any 3 products as a showcase product (separate columns)

Comment: Can't you simply add a column to product "isShowcase" and just set true for the showcase products of their category? You would have to build the logic to limit it to 3 for each catergory, but that  is also the case for your current solution.

Comment: @A.Copter sadly I cant. Because the product may or may not be from the same category. for example for a category 'meat' a showcase product can be some plant based stuff as a substitute for meat product. also, there are sub-categories that would create a whole new issue.

Comment: From a pure SQL point of view your second approach with a M:N Table for the showcases should be able to deliver the wanted results. I'm not familar with this the ORM but in the documentation they use belongsToMany instead of hasMany - maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: @A.Copter with pure sql and even with Laravel i managed to make it. but with october i cant. I tried `hasMany` also `belongsToMany` and many different stuff. What happens is October seems to ignore the second relationship and default to the first `Product > Category` one (ignoring showcase relationship) when generating the form.